# backbone default error fetch function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm having difficulty picking up the fundamentals of backbone.

In my app, I have a resource Goals.  Users can have subsets of goals relavent to them.  If I fetch a collection of goals fro /my_goals, are they considered saved in a generic collection of goals?  Is there a way to ask for goal 46, have it loaded from the collection if found, and requested from the server otherwise?

Comment: If you're asking for goal 46 and it's not in your collection, is the idea that it may have been added to the server's datastore after you initially populated your collection?

Comment: I'm asking for goal 46 outside of the context of the collection.  Do I want to stay in that context, and use #get?  What if goal 46 isin't part of that collection of goals, but may be part of another?

Comment: The scenario wouldn't really make sense in the context of using a backbone collection. The url specified for your resource won't change, so unless you're anticipating goal 46 being added after you've initially populated your collection, you won't be retrieving it with that collection.

Comment: So if I'm going to be sharing collections between multiple views, where's a good place to keep instantiated collections?

Comment: Is it not feasible to store all your goals in one collection and just retrieve them as needed? It's difficult to suggest anything without better understanding how you need to model your data and it's relationship to other actors in your app.

Comment: It may be feasible!  Leads to the next question-- is it possible to do a simple select for a subset of group of nodes in a collection? such as ones having a particular property?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7063/discussion-between-peter-ehrlich-and-kinakuta)

Comment: So retrieve all models from the collection where one of the attributes = something you specify?

Answer (score 0):

Is Goal46 not a model which can be loaded from the model instead using URLROOT?